# How to re-run only failed tests (failed data row) in visual studio test task?

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, azure-pipelines-build-task, browserstack, vstest

We have a build pipeline for our automated scripts (selenium) in Azure-Devops. And we use browserstack to run all our scripts. Sometimes we get timeout issue, no matter what we implement additional options to browser settings we still get timeout. So we decided to re run the tests to certain limit and then the pass percentage went high and scripts were passed without any issues.

So we have different data rows for each test method. Now when a test method for a particular data row is failed then the entire test (including all the passed data row) are getting executed again in the re-run which is unnecessary since some are passed.

Is there any way to run only failed data row test ?

As seen in below screenshot on the regular attempt, data row 0 is failed and others passed. So it goes for re-run and running all the passed test again.

[Test result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMQJI.png)

Note: Using Batch option to re-run the failed tests. Also tried with Automatic batch option where it failed to re-run because of test name issue of vstest.console.exe (There is formatting issue if the test name has spaces or round braces)

Comment: It seems that it is by design that rerun failed tests will rerun passed tests too for data driven tests, you can refer an issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/8130). You can also submit this issue there.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT ya I checked that. Thank you. Hope they fix it soon.